# ごめんなさい　How do I say that I am sorry in a deeply apologetic manner?

Tags: meaning, words

Recently, I posted content concerning questions and answers from this website to another without providing proper attribution to the posters and commenters. I want to say that I am sorry, but also convey a deeper sense of apology. Are there additional words or phrases that can be used to express a deeper remorse? Thank you.

Comment: 「すみませんでした」 (filler)

Comment: Perhaps one of these? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/38823/19206

Comment: Please post an answer, if possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A standard formal apology would be 申し訳ありません, which can be made more formal as 申し訳ございません. For an extremely formal apology (for example, a CEO making a public apology for their company's misconduct), お詫び申し上げます might be good. Optionally, you could say 心より or 誠に before either of them.

Comment: +1 for 申し訳ございません and not 申し訳ないでございます. The latter I've heard before and have also been previously warned to not be correct by instructors of mine in the past.